# Getting data from a DynamoDb table into an HTML table using API Gateway

Tags: javascript, arrays, aws-api-gateway

I've managed to query a DynamoDb table using Lambda triggered by an API Gateway. Clicking on the API URL gives me this:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "date": "1522395676041",
      "UUID": "2deed071-f2ad-46f8-b30f-69e2da55d4c9",
      "message": "0941 from John",
      "commentId": "ba6c3749-33ed-11e8-95a6-0f2f6e50e87f",
      "reason": "1",
      "pageId": "0"
    },
    {
      "date": "1522685413383",
      "UUID": "085b71b3-98a9-4155-be19-a6c221b3d60a",
      "message": "0933",
      "commentId": "53c9bb19-3690-11e8-abfb-b5a9138e7fe2",
      "reason": "1",
      "pageId": "0"
    },
    {
      "date": "1522574265688",
      "UUID": "2deed071-f2ad-46f8-b30f-69e2da55d4c9",
      "message": "1117 from John‘s iPhone",
      "commentId": "8a3cc78a-358d-11e8-803c-659d2c124a1d",
      "reason": "1",
      "pageId": "0"
    },
 ],
  "Count": 3,
  "ScannedCount": 3
}
```

I can't work out how to get these into a simple array so that Javascript can  send it to a table (I am using the Convert JSON To Table library). I've looked at AWS API Gateway templates and JavaScript examples but they don't really help.

Does anyone know of an easier way?

Cheers,

JC

Comment: How does this differ from what you are calling a "simple array"?

Comment: Hi Michael, it's an array in an object. I'm not sure how to get it into a table, to do that I guess I would have to make it look like this:[
    [{
      "date": "1522395676041",
      "UUID": "2deed071-f2ad-46f8-b30f-69e2da55d4c9",
      "message": "0941 from John",
      "commentId": "ba6c3749-33ed-11e8-95a6-0f2f6e50e87f",
      "reason": "1",
      "pageId": "0"
    },
    {
      "date": "1522685413383",
      "UUID": "085b71b3-98a9-4155-be19-a6c221b3d60a",
  ...
      "pageId": "0"
    }, ---
    
 ],

Comment: With apologies if I am stating the obvious... if the outer object is `foo` then `let my_array = foo.Items;` and you have your array.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Michael, I've spent a couple of days looking at everything but the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using this jquery plugin called - [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/). You won't need to write HTML or any other DOM generating code.

Or if you'd like to build your own html custom table then, use array.map() function in javascript.